# Does llvm/clang still need MinGW gcc after built?

Tags: gcc, mingw, llvm, clang

I am new to llvm/clang and have successfully built clang with MinGW.

I have one simple question - is MinGW gcc still needed for clang to work as a c/c++ compiler?

Thanks,
jweiboman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now - unfortunately, yes. clang will use gcc to assemble / link the stuff. This is necessary to e.g. provide the proper cmdline for linker invocation adding CRT objects & libraries.

As soon as someone will provide the the complete "toolchain" definition for mingw in clang, this won't be necessary. Only assembler and linker (part of binutils) will be required.

Comment: Is it worth working on the toolchain definition before the Driver is rewritten? There are a lot of subleties (like mingw.org vs mingw-w64) which might be difficult to get right without some form of general driver input file.

Comment: @rubenvb - I think yes. At least the result will be the knowledge how all the stuff should be organized. One can start from small thing, e.g. trying to figure out where Mingw is installed, etc.

Comment: Is it really? When I run clang 3.0 on .cpp file, it calls link.exe from Microsoft Visual Studio, not MinGW to link .obj file produced by clang into .exe.

Comment: @Mārtiņš That's probably because your clang binary was built with Visual Studio. Clang remembers the toolchain that was used to build it and uses that information when looking for standard header files, and possibly linker.

Comment: But that means that MinGW is not mandatory for using clang under Windows, right?

Comment: If you have only C code - then yes. Situation is much worse with C++ due to many reasons.

Comment: It seems that LLVM provided their own linker, LLD, why Clang still uses's GNU ld? Thanks.